# Cut div box into two in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

[image: This is what i want]I need to cut my below div boxes into two.Please help me out[image: This is my div box]

And My HTML Code is
'

<div *ngFor="let value of dashBoardTableList ;let i=index"
myStyleDirective

```
     [ngClass]="value.crDt==1 ? 'table5' : 'table3' " 
    itemIndex="i"
    (click)="navToOrder(value.agId,value.invoiceId,value.tableNo,value.currStageName)"
    [style.background-color]="value.currStageColor"
    class="table1 m-3" 
    tooltip={{value.currStageName}}
    placement="top">
           <span class="homeTopLabel ">{{value.noOfCovers}}</span>
        <span class="leftGlass">
            <i *ngIf="value.currStageName!='Empty'" class="fa fa-glass "></i>
            <i *ngIf="value.currStageName=='Empty'" class=" fa fa-glass fa-flip-vertical"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="fa-stack middlePlate">
            <i class="fa fa-genderless fa-stack-2x" style="font-size:35px;"></i><i class="fa fa-spoon fa-stack-1x"
                style="font-size: 15px;top: 5px;left: -1.5px;"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="rightGlass">
            <i *ngIf="value.currStageName!='Empty'" class="fa fa-glass "></i>
            <i *ngIf="value.currStageName=='Empty'" class=" fa fa-glass fa-flip-vertical"></i>
        </span>

        <span class="homeBlabel">{{value.tableNo}}</span>

    </div>
</div> '
```

Comment: cut into two div means ?

Comment: Hi @G need to cut the boxes into two halves either horizontally or vertical

Comment: Cut means ? what type of content do you need to show into two divs after split it out ?

Comment: empty space in the middle.

Comment: Yes sure .wicky11casillas@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Grid

```
.parent {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
grid-column-gap: 0px;
grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

.div1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2; }
.div2 { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; }
.div3 { grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="div1"> </div>
<div class="div2"> </div>
<div class="div3"> </div>
</div>
```

You can also try complex grids from here :

https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.app/